# Call JS function from QML when JS code is not known at app build time (hat tip SpiderMonkey)

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, qml

I am interested in the possibilities of calling JavaScript from C++ in QML. The problem that I see is that JavaScript functions need to be compiled with the application before I can invoke them. Rather, I would like to dynamically read the code for a JavaScript function from a file and have it interpreted on demand like I can do with Mozilla's SpiderMonkey.
Is this possible with Qt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do that:

- Use the "evil" `eval()` to return a function object from a string
- Use `Qt.createQmlObject()` to create a QML object from a string that has the function as a member

Then you can pass the function to C++ as a `QJSValue` which you can `call(QJSValueList &args)`.